# how to fill in scroll view from file or database or any data source?

Tags: android

I want to bind data from an xml file? how can I do that where i'm using a layout xml file to define a scrollview ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i've understood your question right, you want to read a layout file and insert it into a ScrollView.

You would want to take a look LayoutInflater for this task.
Example for doing this from an activity.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
ScrollView sv = findViewById(R.id.id_of_scrollview);
inflater.inflate(R.layout.id_of_layoutfile_to_include, sv);
```

EDIT:
After having read your comment i realise that i misunderstood your question.

ScrollView is not the view you want for binding your data, scrollView is a specialized frameLayout, and therefore only allows one child.

Your most likely looking for a view like [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) (Which adds scrolling automatically)

Another solution is to use a Layout in a scrollview and dynamically (From code) add the views.

```
LinearLayout ll = findViewById(R.id.id_of_linearlayout);
//Loop data and build a view for each data entry and add it with 
ll.addView(yourView);
```

Comment: i have a data stored in xml file, i want to display this data in scrollview

Comment: Then what your looking for is another control for this. (for an example ListView)

Comment: thanks dear do you have an example for >> Another solution is to use a Layout in a scrollview and dynamically (From code) add the views.

Comment: Have added it now, however i find that going the listview route will save you alot of work! Good luck